# How to fix driver-side window controls malfunction [Toyota Camry XLE 2010]

Tags: toyota, camry, power-windows, switches

I have a problem with my Driver side window controls
Car: Toyota Camry 2010 XLE

Situation:
I took my car into an auto shop to get my tinting redone. After, they were done putting on the tinting (took them about 26 hours), they told me not to put the windows down for 3 - 5 days to let the tinting cure properly. After the 5th day, I tried to put down all the windows in the car as I was driving. Only the front two windows were able to go down. The back two windows did not go down.
I did go to the back of the car later and tried the individual window controls for the back right and left windows. Those individual controls worked and the windows were able to go down.

I have some video from my dashcam of the mechanics working on my car and I saw they used a battery of some sort attached to my car battery to operate the windows, possibly to circumvent turning on the car I assume(?).

Hypothesis:
I believe that either something is wrong with the window control buttons on the driver's side door; maybe the constant spraying with their liquid solution seeped into the controls
OR
a relay for the window controls is burnt out or is missing from my relay box.

Can I get y'alls expert opinion? I would like to fix this problem myself if I can, especially since I caught the auto shop stealing property from my car.

[image: Relay Pciture 1]

Comment: Have you got a wiring diagram for the windows for the vehicle?